# Is there a memory leak? Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run this code. I get high memory usage such that my ram hits 100% and my PC will freeze for hours. I see little to no gpu usage while monitoring with Nvidia-Smi. The cpu usage is around 20-30%. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Is the code running on cuda?

```
class RL_Agents:
    def __init__(self, building_info, observation_spaces=None, action_spaces=None):
# Parameters
        self.device = "cpu"
        self.time_step = 0
        self.building_info = building_info  # Can be used to create different RL agents based on basic building attributes or climate zones
        self.observation_spaces = observation_spaces
        self.action_spaces = action_spaces
        self.n_buildings = len(observation_spaces)
        self.buffer = {i: Buffer() for i in range(self.n_buildings)}
        self.networks_initialized = False
```

Comment: Are you doing `model.cuda()`?

Comment: No. can I do critic = critic.cuda() ? 
And the same for actor as well?

Comment: You can just do `<your_model>.cuda()`; No need to re-assign it back to `<your_model>`

Comment: I did that too. But memory usage still hitting 100% causing pc to freeze.

Comment: Well your arch looks so small, why would it cause RAM to go 100%?

Comment: I was wondering whether to change that self.device to "cuda" will help. I tried changing to cuda but encountered errors.